# I added a dynamic updater using removeAllItems() and addItem(). Things went wrong afterwards. What happened and how can I fix it?

Tags: java, swing

I just tested a method to change a `JComboBox`'s list by removing, and then adding items (see method `public void SetComboBoxOptions`). After adding said functionality, conversion of mass failed. I believe the indexes are somehow not referring to the right thing. What can I do?

I am using JDK 11.0.1, on a Windows 10 laptop. I have already tried changing the implementation of function `public double weightConvert` and it does not work.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class UnitConverter extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    String[] weightUnits = {"kg", "g", "mg", "lb", "oz", "gr"};
    String[] distanceUnits = {"km", "m", "cm", "mm", "mi", "yd", "ft",
    "in"};
    String[] types = {"Mass", "Distance"};
    DefaultComboBoxModel weight = new
            DefaultComboBoxModel(weightUnits);
    DefaultComboBoxModel distance = new
            DefaultComboBoxModel(distanceUnits);
    // selector boxes
    JComboBox box1 = new JComboBox(weightUnits);
    JComboBox box2 = new JComboBox(weightUnits);
    JComboBox box3 = new JComboBox(types);
    // text fields
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField(20);
    // buttons
    JButton button1 =  new JButton("CONVERT");
    public UnitConverter()
    {
        //creating window
        super("Unit Converter"); // calls javax.swing.JFrame
        constructor setting title
        setSize(500, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        //adding action listeners
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        box3.addActionListener(this);
        //putting window together
        grid.add(box1);
        grid.add(field1);
        grid.add(box2);
        grid.add(field2);
        contentPane.add("Center", grid);
        contentPane.add("North", box3);
        contentPane.add("East", button1);
    }
    public void SetComboBoxOptions(String[] stuff, JComboBox box)
    {
        box.removeAllItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
        {
            box.addItem(stuff[i]);
        }
    }
    public double weightConvert(double in, String from, String to)
    {
        double result = in;
        switch (from)
        {
        case "kg": result *= 1000;
        case "g": result *= 1000;
        case "mg": result *= 1; break;
        case "lb": result *= 16;
        case "oz": result *= 437.5;
        case "gr": result *= 64.79891; break;
        default: result *= 0; break;
        }
        switch (to)
        {
        case "kg": result /= 1000;
        case "g": result /= 1000;
        case "mg": result /= 1; break;
        case "lb": result /= 16;
        case "oz": result /= 437.5;
        case "gr": result /= 64.79891; break;
        default: result *= 0; break;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public double distanceConvert(double in, String from, String to)
    {
        double result = in;
        switch (from)
        {
        case "km": result *= 1000;
        case "m": result *= 100;
        case "cm": result *= 10;
        case "mm": result *= 1; break;
        case "mi": result *= 1760;
        case "yd": result *= 3;
        case "ft": result *= 12;
        case "in": result *= 25.4; break;
        default: result *= 0; break;
        }
        switch (to)
        {
        case "km": result /= 1000;
        case "m": result /= 100;
        case "cm": result /= 10;
        case "mm": result /= 1; break;
        case "mi": result /= 1760;
        case "yd":   result /= 3;
        case "ft":   result /= 12;
        case "in":   result /= 25.4; break;
        default: result *= 0; break;
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource() == button1)
        {
            switch (box3.getSelectedIndex())
            {
            case 0: field2.setText(Double.toString(weightConvert(Double.parseDouble(field1.getText()), weightUnits[box1.getSelectedIndex()], weightUnits[box2.getSelectedIndex()])));
            case 1: field2.setText(Double.toString(distanceConvert(Double.parseDouble(field1.getText()), distanceUnits[box1.getSelectedIndex()], distanceUnits[box2.getSelectedIndex()])));
            }
        }
        if (event.getSource() == box3)
        {
            switch (box3.getSelectedIndex())
            {
            case 0: SetComboBoxOptions(weightUnits, box1);
            SetComboBoxOptions(weightUnits, box2); break;
            case 1: SetComboBoxOptions(distanceUnits, box1);
            SetComboBoxOptions(distanceUnits, box2); break;
            default: SetComboBoxOptions(weightUnits, box1);
            SetComboBoxOptions(weightUnits, box2); break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        UnitConverter XD = new UnitConverter();
    }
}
```

I expected conversion of 20 kg to give about 44 lb. However, I see that 20 kg gives 2.0E7 lb.

Comment: Your code is a bit complex, and you may have better luck if you could simplify the problem into a decent [mcve], the smallest code that will compile, run and demonstrate the problem. Having said that, if this were my project, I'd create an enum to encapsulate the weight and length units, typing the type name to its conversion factor, and then have my JComboBox display the enum itself, so that the conversion factor would be included in the objects held by the JComboBox.

Comment: Your conversion factors don't look to be fully correct. Always a good idea to separate the GUI from the logic part of the code, and test them separately.

Comment: Use the **break;** statement at the end of **every** case block otherwise all statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Comment: @DevilsHnd you are absolutely right. Unfortunately the poor implementation requires execution of several consecutive  cases.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Wow, how have I not noticed? :P Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the small issue you have, add a break :

```
case 0: field2.setText(Double.toString(weightConvert(Double.parseDouble(field1.getText()), weightUnits[box1.getSelectedIndex()], weightUnits[box2.getSelectedIndex()])));
        break; //missing
```

For much better implementation note the important comments: 
 [Always a good idea to separate the GUI from the logic part of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892510/i-added-a-dynamic-updater-using-removeallitems-and-additem-things-went-wron#comment94632228_53892510)

[Use the break; statement at the end of every case block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892510/i-added-a-dynamic-updater-using-removeallitems-and-additem-things-went-wron#comment94632969_53892510) which means rethink the conversions logic.

A simple conversion implementation could look like:

```
class Convertor{

    private static final double KG_TO_GRAM = 1000, LBS_TO_GRAM = 453.592;

    private double value;
    public Convertor(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Convertor kgToGr(){
        value *= KG_TO_GRAM;
        return this;
    }

    Convertor grToKg(){
        value /= KG_TO_GRAM;
        return this;
    }

    Convertor lbToGr(){
        value /= LBS_TO_GRAM;
        return this;
    }

    Convertor grToLb(){
        value /= LBS_TO_GRAM;
        return this;
    }

    double getValue() {return value;}
}
```

Testing it by

```
 System.out.println(new Convertor(20).kgToGr().grToLb().getValue());
```

prints out the expected value.